# program for solving equation in c#

Tags: c#, math

x+2y=8 , 2x+y=14  this are equations this is just example i gave for understanding . from this equation i like to find x,y values using c# program anybody help for me.how can implement this in program?...

Comment: Is the input constrained to linear equasions?

Comment: `<joke> for(x = int.MinValue ; x != int.MaxValue ; x++) for(y = int.MinValue ; y != int.MaxValue ; y++) if(((x + 2 * y) == 8) && ((2 * y + y) == 14)) { Console.WriteLine("x={0}, y={1}", x, y); } </joke>`

Comment: This smells like homework, if so tag it as so!! :)

Comment: You have to show your work!  Didn't anyone ever tell you that?  I imagine I have just complicated your situation by an order of magnitude or so...=D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to follow several steps:

1. You need to have a parser, to pass these two equations.
2. Then you can use method like [Solving Systems of Equations with Matrices](http://www.algebralab.org/lessons/lesson.aspx?file=Algebra_matrix_systems.xml) ( for linear systems)

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) also shows some different options.

However as already stated you need to turn these equations into matrices first.